# SQL statement to include missing Attributes

Tags: sql

I have a statement like

TableA

```
ID    X
1     x1
2     x2
3     x3
```

TableB

```
ID    AttributeName      AttributeValue
1     Type               some
2     not                nothing
3     Type               other
```

I now want a result like

```
1,x1,some
2,x2,''
3,x3,other
```

The SQL

```
SELECT TableA.ID, TableA.X, TableB.AttributeValue
FROM TableA, TableB
WHERE TableA.ID = TableB.ID AND TableB.AttributeName = 'Type'
```

gives me all IDs with X and TypeDescription where the Attribute Type exists.
But I also want the IDs where no Type is set included - how to reach that?

Comment: Do you have a row with ID = 2 in TableB? If not, remove it from the questions please

Comment: @gbn I think you didn't understood the question

Comment: Probably, but there can be semantic differences between "rows exists but not "Type" an "no rows exists".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an outer join:

```
SELECT TableA.ID, TableA.X, TableB.AttributeValue
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID AND TableB.AttributeName = 'Type'
```

This will return a `NULL`, not an empty string `''`  for id=2. If you need an empty string instead, use coalesce. On SQL Server it would look like this:

```
SELECT TableA.ID, TableA.X, COALESCE(TableB.AttributeValue, '')
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID AND TableB.AttributeName = 'Type'
```